# Unity3D 3 player movement in relation to 1 of the 3 roads

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a simple 3D runner.

But I have a problem with the player movement because I have 3 roads (blue, green, red), and I want that when the player swipes (or clicks) he moves only from one road to another. **Consequently this is not free movements.**

My initial idea was to assign a number to each road : | -1 | 0 | 1 |. And create some conditions if you're on 1 and you click on right you will not move because there is no road after the red one.

However it doesn't work very well : **It's not precise I want that my player can only move from road to road (one click/swipe one road)**

[image: Image of the prototype]

```
// If we click to left and the position of the player is 0 or 1
if (Input.GetKey("left") && (playerPosition == 0 || playerPosition == 1))
{
    // Change direction to left
        endPosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x - 1, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    playerPosition = playerPosition - 1;

    Debug.Log("playerPosition Left : " + playerPosition);
}

if (Input.GetKey("right") && (playerPosition == -1 || playerPosition == 0))
{
    // Change direction to right
    endPosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x + 1, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    playerPosition = playerPosition + 1;
    Debug.Log("playerPosition Right : " + playerPosition);
}

gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(direction, endPosition, speed);
```

Do you have **some advices about how to move this player in relation to the road?**

Thanks and have a good day!

Comment: What is the error you are getting? "However it doesn't work very well." doesn't really explain your problem! :)

Comment: I have no errors however the problem is that when I click on left or right the player move but he don't fit in a road. Consequently I want that the player can only move road to road.

Comment: I think you should store three positions. When the player moves, place the player on one of those stored position. It looks like you are only translating the player relative to its current position, am i right?

Comment: As your approach is not very good (i.e. you are new to this it seems) I would stay with @Poonuts solution. Create 3 gameobjects (without renderes) and place them in hierarchy under the road, so they will move with the road (or under the player object, so they will stay in position relative to the player, whichever fits best). Then on move, you just align the player to one of those "markers"/gameobjects (player.x = goRedTrackMarker.x; player.z = goRedTrackMarker.z; etc)

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, it looks like your issue is that your player doesn't fit in the road.

I'd guess this is because your scale of your roads are bigger than 1, and you are moving your player 1 unit left or right, which does not correspond to the size of each of your roads.

A way to get around this is to store the positions of the roads (e.g. the center of the road) as an empty gameobject. You could then align your player with one of the empty gameobjects when you move your player.

Your code may look like something like this:

```
//this assumes that your script is on your player

//assign these in the inspector
public GameObject leftRoad, centerRoad, rightRoad; //the empty gameobjects which lie in the center of your roads

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey("left"))
    {
        // Change direction to left
        transform.position = leftRoad.position;

    }
    if (Input.GetKey("right"))
    {
        // Change direction to right
        transform.position = rightRoad.position;
    }    

    gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(direction, endPosition, speed);
}
```

***NOTE***

This is only a simple idea of how to transition to the left or to the right from the center. You will have to do a bit more coding to get other movement, such as moving from the left road back to the center.

Comment: it's a nice approach.